# match without duplicating entry - MS ACCESS

Tags: duplicates, ms-access-2010, match

I'm trying to do an outer join of the techID from table1 to pull the date from table 2.  The problem is the techID is duplicated multiple times in each table. I want the dates to be listed in order but stop matching once there are no more data. For example

```
techID |Order#
tech1   order1
tech2   order2
tech3   order3
tech4   order4
tech3   order5
tech3   order6

techID |Month
tech3   Oct-01
tech3   Nov-02
tech2   Jan-10
tech1   Jan-11
tech1   Feb-02
tech4   Feb-04

output
tech1   Feb-02
tech2   Jan-10
tech3   Oct-01
tech4   Feb-04
tech3   Nov-02
tech3
```

Right now All I have is a subquery but it's nowhere close to what I need...HELP!

```
(select last(table2.[shipping_date])
from table2
where  table1.techid = table2.techid ) AS shippedon
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is INNER JOIN with the MAX on the Month field and GROUP BY on the techID. Something like

```
SELECT 
    techTableName.techID, 
    Max(projectTableName.monthFieldName) As MaxOfMonth
FROM
    techTableName 
    INNER JOIN
    projectTableName
    ON 
    techTableName.techID = projectTableName.techID
GROUP BY 
    techTableName.techID;
```

However, I do not see any point in **JOIN**ing them, this assumption is based on the Data Set you have provided, the Query could be simply.

```
SELECT 
    projectTableName.techID, 
    Max(projectTableName.monthFieldName) As MaxOfMonth
FROM
    projectTableName
GROUP BY 
    projectTableName.techID
```

Comment: I want to see all the shipping dates not just the last one.  Will this work? Tech names shows up three times and there's 2 shipping dates. I want to see both that shipping dates as well as the fact that one techname doesn't have a shipping date.

Comment: Please edit your original post with the right data and output you wish to see.